# Spring dependency injection using setter method?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6

I have below classes.

```
public class SomeBeanClass implements SomeInterface{


    private IAccountHistory acctHistory;

    public void setAccountHistory(IAccountHistory  acctHistory) {
        this.acctHistory = acctHistory;
    }

}


public interface IAccountHistory{
 //some methods
}

public class AccountHistory implements IAccountHistory{
  //some logic
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<bean name="someBean" class="com.mypack.SomeBeanClass">
        <property name="AccountHistory">
            <bean class="com.mypack.AccountHistory"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

In above spring configuration, property name is `AccountHistory` . But `SomeBeanClass` does not have any property named `AccountHistory`. How is injection working here? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But `SomeBeanClass` does not have any property named `AccountHistory`.

It does, right here:

```
public void setAccountHistory(IAccountHistory  acctHistory) {
    this.acctHistory = acctHistory;
}
```

A *property* isn't a *field*. It is a Java bean property (with a few extra naming allowances) represented with a getter or setter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is setAccountHistory is a field here?

Comment: @user755806 No. `acctHistory` is a field. Please read a basic tutorial to learn the nomenclature. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: But acctHistory is not mentioned in spring configuraation file.

Comment: @user755806 Exactly. Spring doesn't care about it. It cares about _properties_.

Comment: If I change property name="AccountHistory" to property name="acctHistory" is spring config then is it wrong?

Comment: @user755806 Yes, **`SomeBeanClass` does not have a property named `acctHistory`**.

Comment: Here I am really confused. in spring config I have property name="AccountHistory". Then what spring looks for in SomeBeanClass ?Can I change setAccountHistory to setAcctHistory ?

Comment: Please reread my answer. Spring looks for _Java bean properties_ (those are keywords, look them up). Your `SomeBeanClass` class has a property named `AccountHistory` from its setter `setAccountHistory`. It uses that to inject a bean of type `IAccountHistory`.

Answer (score -4):

Please update your XML to

```
<bean id="accountHistory" class="com.package.AccountHistory" />
<bean id="someBean" class="com.mypack.SomeBeanClass">
     <property name="acctHistory" ref="accountHistory"/>          
</bean>
```

I would recommend to use annotation, if you have a good reason to use XML then please go ahead.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am confused here. what is the difference between your answer and my code <bean name="someBean" class="com.mypack.SomeBeanClass">
        <property name="AccountHistory">
            <bean class="com.mypack.AccountHistory"/>
        </property>
</bean>

Comment: What do you think this will change and why do you think so?